# Eliminate all Windows Remote Desktop Connection warnings

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I use Windows RDP to connect to a variety of Windows operating systems. Sometimes I get security prompts (even after checking "don't display this again") relating to certificates, other times related to use of the Clipboard, or Drives. It is extremely annoying. How do I make all of these warning dialogs go away permanently?

EDIT: Just wanted to add, many of these are customers' computers, so I am not authorized to fix their certificates.

Comment: Fix the certificates on the server.

Comment: There is an option for Certificate warnings. When you start RDP click on options and then on the last tab "advanced" you will see there is an option to "igonore certificates and connect". There are as well a lot of other options. When i use rdp i only get the certificate error cause i havent changed it yet.

Comment: Use an alternate client like mremoteng?